# Creating a large array of objects Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to display a list of items from a database in an "A to Z" fashion. This list of items is > 1200. My question is: can I simply use NSArray? Or would it be better to use something like an NSDictionary? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want them to be ordered in A to Z fashion, you'd be better off using an NSArray since it can be sorted, as opposed to a NSDictionary

Comment: Displaying that a list of that size efficiently is a much bigger problem than storing it. It's really a small number of items for a computer — computers routinely handle lists of millions — but it's a lot for displaying in the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key hint I see in your question is "In A to Z fashion." Arrays save an ordered collection of objects. To present a collection of things in A to Z order, they need to be ordered.

Sets and dictionaries are unordered collections.

There is a small amount of overhead in using objects to save data instead of using simple memory structures. If you were dealing with hundreds of thousands -or millions- of things, that overhead could become a consideration. But with a 4-digit number of items, it is not a concern.

NSArrays store objects. If you are already saving your things in objets, NSArray/NSMutableArray is an excellent choice for organizing your objects.

As the other poster said, if you're dealing with very large numbers of objects, you should think about using a database system like sql, but at your current scale, an in-memory solution should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. What I am basically trying to accomplish is this: We have a collection of products, for example Pepsi and there are several "brands", each with different sizes (i.e. 12oz, 20oz, etc). Each of these has a unique product number, but what is requested is a A - Z list of these items that can be displayed in a UITableView and then scrolled or searched. We currently sort them by brand, then size, then package, but the request is ALL items. My question mainly concerned memory and load times when popping this view.

Comment: 1200 items is not enough for you to worry about memory. User experience is the only real issue. You will want an index tab, like Apple's Contacts app, so the user can select a letter of the alphabet. You will probably also want a search bar so the user can filter the list of choices and find the one they are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't sufficient information in your question to know whether to use an array or a dictionary (or a set). Everything depends on how you want to access these things. If by keyword, it's a dictionary. If by index number, it's an array. And so on.

Certainly the *number* of elements (which appears in your question) is irrelevant to the choice. A collection of 1200 things is a collection of 1200 things, no matter what kind of collection it is. And 1200 is tiny. If it were 12000, or 120000, you might start thinking of keeping a real database on disk - and *no* kind of collection in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have duplicates and you want to iterate over your collection, you should use NSArray.

Choose your data structure thinking how are you going to use and access the information stored in it.